# Trip from New Delhi to Dusseldorf via Munich: Where will I pass through Immigration?

Tags: transit, customs-and-immigration, germany, airports, muc

I will be traveling from New Delhi (India) to Dusseldorf (Germany), with a layover in Munich (Germany), flying on Lufthansa.

Will immigration happen at Munich or Dusseldorf?

Would a layover of 2 hours in Munich be enough to require a change of planes?

Comment: I have cleaned up your question a bit, if you disagree with my changes, please feel free to roll them back. I have also added the Indian Citizen tag, although you did not specify it, it would be very helpful if you confirmed your citizenship.

Comment: @CGCampbell and OP: I have further edited tags since I found them slightly more relevant, feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immigration happens in Munich (i.e. where you are first arriving in the Schengen area).

Two hours should be enough time to pass through immigration and change planes. If both of your flights are on one booking in fact Lufthansa will get you on a later flight to Dusseldorf in case of delays and deems that time enough since they were willing to sell you this ticket.